# Can't Unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt 20.4

Tags: boot, encryption

First off I'm dumb as it gets with computers

Installed 20.4. using a bootable USB. Set ssd as install path for Ubuntu. Full encryption. I don't think in the installation process I entered a encryption passcode. Only security keys, which dont work for 'nvme0n1p3_crypt'disk code.

I also get this trying boot in recovery mode (Linux 5.11.0-46- generic & 5.11.0-27- generic versions)

Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgubuntu
Please unlock dusk nvme0n1p3_crypt

Have tried editing in advanced settings the Linux code in Grub replacing 'ro' with 'rm' then 'init=/bin/bash. Removing 'nomodeset dis_ucode_1dr'
Using Linux 5.11.0-46 generic (recovery mode) & normal generic

Same with 5.11.0-27 generic versions

Shot my self in the foot lol.

Any suggestions appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Reinstall and don't forget the passphrase? Or don't use encryption because it's an additional and heavy layer of difficulty for newbies.

Comment: Reinstall? How do I go about doing that? Can't access anything on computer other than Ubuntu boot which locks me out.

Comment: Reinstall the exact same way you installed it in the first time. Drive encryption doesn't prevent it being overwritten by a new installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start over and reinstall the operating system.

Choose the "Erase Disk and Install" option.  Alternatively, you can use the "Disks" application to format the hard drive while booted in the live session (Try Ubuntu). Then you can begin the installation.

I do not agree with comments that suggest that whole disk encryption is inappropriate or difficult for "newbies". The only additional step is that you will need to provide your decryption key every time you boot. I do not find that to be confusing or difficult, however you will obviously need to remember the passphrase.

As you are currently experiencing, without the decryption passphrase, you will not be able to boot the installation, nor will you be able to access any data on the encrypted partition.